# jQuery + XML and for()

Tags: jquery, for-loop, html-entities

I am making a website with portions of the page updated with XML. Most of the DOM scripting is accomplished with jQuery however to parse the XML I am using a for() loop.

1. Is there are more native way to accomplish this in jQuery?
2. I can't seem to store the XML as an array. Is there something wrong here?
3. How do I deal with HTML entities / special characters?

   ```
   function getPortfolioText(path)
   {
   var linkArray= new Array();
   if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
   {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
   xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   }else{// code for IE6, IE5
   xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }
   xmlhttp.open("GET",'images/'+path+"/note1.xml",false);
   xmlhttp.send();
   xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;
   document.getElementById("message").innerHTML="<p class='attributes'>project  description</p>"+xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;    
   for (var i = 0; i < xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("links")[0].childNodes.length; i++)     {
   linkArray[i]=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("p")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
   };
   };
   ```

and here is my XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
    <note>
    <links>
    <p>http://url.com/two/images/0.jpg</p>
    <p>http://url.com/two/images/1.jpg</p>
    <p>http://url.com/two/images/2.jpg</p>
    <p>http://url.com/two/images/3.jpg</p>
    </links>
    <body>text description &amp; please include html entities.</body>
    </note>
```

Comment: Why you are not using jquery `.get()` ajax function

Comment: I have never used get before.
1. What about getting the XML and parsing it to an array?